# JQuery not displaying HTML data from ajax response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Howdie do,

I have a form that simply takes a username and email from a user. The input is sanitiazed via client and on the server side.

The script is sending the POST with no issue and it's returning the data as it should be as I've checked in the log.  However, for some reason, the data isn't being displayed in the browser.

Code is below and I feel it's a stupid item I'm overlooking, but I can't find it anywhere

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Jeremy's Form Submit Test </TITLE>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
        $("#FormSubmit").click(function() //Set click action on formsubmit button
        {
                var submit = true;
                $('#MainForm input[type="text"]').each(function() //Loop through input fields to ensure data is present
                {
                    if($.trim($('#User').val()) == '') //Remove whitespaces and check if field is empty
                    {
                        alert('Input can not be blank');
                        submit = false;
                    }

                    var regex = /^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$/; //RegEx to test email against
                    if(!regex.test($.trim($('#Email').val()))) //If supplied email without whitespaces doesn't match pattern, then alert user
                    {
                        alert('Please provide a valid email');
                        submit = false;
                    }
                });
                if(submit == true) //If data is present, then prepare email and user values to be submitted to .php page
                {
                    data = {'user_name': $('#User').val(), 'email': $('#Email').val()}; //Add username and email to array
                    $.post("success.php", data, function(ReturnedData) //post data via ajx to success.php and retrieve response
                    {
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(ReturnedData));
                        if(ReturnedData.Type == 'Error') //If error returned, display error message
                        {
                            var results = '<h1>'+ReturnedData.Message+'</h1>';
                        }
                        else if(ReturnedData.Type == 'Success') //If success returned, display message and remove submit button
                        {
                            var results = '<h1>'+ReturnedData.Message+'</h1>';
                            $('#FormSubmit').remove();
                        }
                        $('div#DataHolder').html(results);
                    }, 'json');
                }
        });

});
</script>

</HEAD>

<BODY>

<form id="MainForm">
*UserName: <input type="text" id="User" name="FormUsername" required /> 
*Email: <input type="email" id="Email" name="FormEmail" required />
<input type="submit" id="FormSubmit" value="Submit">
</form>

<div id="DataHolder"></div>


</BODY>
</HTML>
```

The PHP file is below that returns a json_encoded response and I've confirmed via the console log that the data is being returned properly, but it's not displaying in the div I've set. The log file is showing the correct response, but it's not displaying:

{"Type":"Error","Message":"UserName must be at least 3 characters!!!"}

```
<?php

if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') //Check apache header to ensure its a json request
{
    $ReturnedData = json_encode(array("Type" => "Error", "Message" => "Naughty naughty. This wasn't an ajax request"));
    die($ReturnedData);
}

if(isset($_POST)) //Ensure that POST is set
{
    //Santiaze the post variables to be double sure no one is up to any funky business
    $SaniUser = filter_var($_POST['user_name'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $SaniEmail = filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

    //Check that username is at least 3 characters and return error if it's not
    if(strlen($SaniUser) != 3)
    {
        $ReturnedData = json_encode(array("Type" => "Error", "Message" => "UserName must be at least 3 characters!!!"));
        die($ReturnedData);
    }
    //Check that email is a valid email
    if(!filter_var($SaniEmail,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    {
        $ReturnedData = json_encode(array("Type" => "Error", "Message" => "Please supply a valid email address!!!"));
        die($ReturnedData);
    }
    //All variables are good. Return successfully message
    $ReturnedData = json_encode(array("Type" => "Success", "Message" => "SUCCESS!!!" .$SaniUser. "Has successfully submitted the form"));
    die($ReturnedData);
}
else
{
    $ReturnedData = json_encode(array("Type" => "Error", "Message" => "Naughty naughty. No data was submitted!!!"));
    die($ReturnedData);
}

?>
```

Comment: My guess is that `ReturnedData` is not an object at this point. I thought you had to specify to jQuery to expect json using `dataType: "json"`. Instead of `console.log(JSON.stringify(ReturnedData));` try `console.log(ReturnedData.Type);` and see if that is `undefined`

Comment: Why is it `$('div#DataHolder')` and not just `$('#DataHolder')`?

Comment: The ReturnedData is an object. That's why you're seeing the message: {"Type":"Error","Message":"UserName must be at least 3 characters!!!"}. If it wasn't an object, the log file wouldn't be showing that data. And I will check the DataHolder now

Answer (score -1):

WOWOWOW the issue was staring me right in the face.

I didn't initialize var results initially when the data is present. So when I called .html(results), the result variable scope was only in the if/else statement.

Setting the variable at the top of the if statement and then setting the returnedData to that value works

Updated code is below:

```
if(submit == true) //If data is present, then prepare email and user values to be submitted to .php page
                {
                    var results;
                    data = {'user_name': $('#User').val(), 'email': $('#Email').val()}; //Add username and email to array
                    $.post("success.php", data, function(ReturnedData) //post data via ajx to success.php and retrieve response
                    {
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(ReturnedData));
                        if(ReturnedData.Type == 'Error') //If error returned, display error message
                        {
                            results = '<h1>'+ReturnedData.Message+'</h1>';
                            //alert(ReturnedData.Message);
                        }
                        else if(ReturnedData.Type == 'Success') //If success returned, display message and remove submit button
                        {
                            $('#FormSubmit').hide();
                            results = '<h1>'+ReturnedData.Message+'</h1>';


                        }
                        $('#DataHolder').html(results);

                    }, 'json');
                }
```

Comment: *"I didn't initialize var results initially when the data is present. So when I called .html(results), the result variable scope was only in the if/else statement."* uhm... that's not how javascript works. if/else statements don't have their own scope. i suspect something else changed that fixed it.

Comment: `$('div#DataHolder')` -> `$('#DataHolder')` possibly? depends on html.

Comment: to be clear, declaring the var outside of the if statement is a good practice, it just isn't what fixed your problem.